# GitHub Actions: find Pull Request after merge and comment on it using an Action

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a GitHub action that is run when a Pull Request is merged, so it is technically run in a the `main` branch, and not against a PR itself or a branch being merged.

In other words, the GitHub action is triggered by the following condition:

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
```

However, I would need this GitHub action to leave a message on a former Pull Request if a certain check is not passed. Is there a way to still access some information about the former pull request after the merge has happened?

Comment: Here is an example: https://github.com/brennerm/github-actions-pr-close-showcase/blob/master/.github/workflows/pr-close.yml